# Load script command on windows not working

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

Trying to run an orientdb script from the command line using:
`console.bat` then the script name e.g. `console.bat myscript.osql`.

When I run the command I get an error
`!Unrecognized command: '?select from TestClass'` (TestClass isnt the real class but it will do).

If I run the commands manually on the console they work as I would expect.

I am on windows 10 creators edition, orientdb 2.2.30.

Comment: Can you share the content of the file? Looks like there might be a syntax error in your query.

Comment: Sure, the file contains a single line:

Comment: Which is select from TestClass;

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're connected to your database and your script is in the same directory as console.bat (bin), you should execute `LOAD SCRIPT myscript.osql` to properly load it.

See [LOAD SCRIPT](https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Console-Command-Load-Script.html) from the docs.